# Ways to clean data (trim unneccesary space & chars) - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am already familiar with methods of cleaning such as, pasting into excel, and running a `TrimClean` Macro.

**example.**

Cell contains text `"Cognac                   "`
I want the result to be `"Cognac"`

Is there an `UPDATE` query which can perform something similar on MySQL?

Comment: Use `VARCHAR`, not `CHAR`.

Comment: Should have mentioned. I already am using varchar. This is a dataset that basically hasn't been cleaned properly during manual processing, and now I have the pleasure of inheriting such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TRIM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
SELECT TRIM('  cognac    ');
-> 'cognac'
```

Or:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH 'x' FROM 'xxxxcognacxxxx')
-> 'cognac'
```

Or cascade multiple characters:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH 'c' FROM (TRIM(BOTH 'x' FROM 'xxxxcognacxxxx')))
-> 'ogna'
```

You can also look at this question for REGEX replace using a function: [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)